# Using AMPscript to see if a value exists in a column inside a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I would like to see if a value exist in a specific column inside a Data Extension, so I can use this in an if statement.

Data Extension for example:
locale_language
'us_es'
'us_en'
'uk_en'
'br_pt'
'pt_pt'
...

So if I try to find the value 'us_ar' I should receive false, and if I try to find 'br_pt', I should receive true.

Thanks,
Felipe

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with the following code

```
    %%[var @exist,@result
    set @exist = rowCount(LOOKUPROWS('Data_Extension','locale_language','us_ar'))
if @exist > 1 
 then 
   set @result = 1 
else 
   set @result = 0 
endif]%%
```

%%=v(@result)=%%

result will return 0 or false

Comment: I would change to `if @exist > 0`  or to `>= 1` as otherwise it will not count if there is only a single row containing that value in the DE.

Comment: Good I will do that

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to achieve but i would prefer to use [IndexOf](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/indexof/#indexof) AmpScript Function like something below -

```
%%[
SET @LocaleLanguage = AttributeValue("locale_language")
SET @SearchString = "us_ar"

IF IndexOf(@LocaleLanguage,@SearchString) == 0 Then
  SET @Result = "False"
Else
  SET @Result = "True"
EndIF
]%%
```

%%=v(@Result)=%%

Comment: If this the field `locale_language` is in a Data Extension that I am not using to send my email campaigns, and actually I am using this to storage some content to be used in my email campaign, how should I look there and see if the value exist inside the field?